# I can't access to array inside structure

Tags: c, struct, printf

I fixed it!

```
  typedef struct student
{
char id[11];
}Student;

 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 int main(int argc, char **argv){
 int input = 0, i = 0;
 FILE * fp = fopen("student.txt", "wt");

if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Error to open student.txt");
    return -1;
}
 scanf("%d",&input);

 student = (Student *)malloc(input*sizeof(Student));

      for(i=0;i<input;i++){
      strcpy(student[i].id, "a"); // A is just for default. 
      fprintf(fp,"%s\n",student[i].id);
 }
 fclose(fp);
 return 0;
 }
```

I've fixed from comments and kind answers.
And it does work

Thanks for help

I really appreciated it! It was really useful.

Comment: What is `student`?

Comment: Why is `student = (Student *)malloc(input*sizeof(Student));` done in a loop? You're just re-assigning a new address to the same pointer, which will leak previous allocations that you didn't free.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Constraint violation when assigning a `char*` to a `char` without a cast?

Comment: Your program is mainly nonsense. Please let us know what exactly you want to do including input, and expected output.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. Because I'm really beginner in codes.
I tried to make code run. That is just what happened inside there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A couple of notes:**

With:

```
for (i=0; i<input; i++)
    student = ...
```

You are repeatedly overriding the value of `student`.

It's pretty much like doing:

```
x = 5;
x = 6;
x = 7;
...
```

Not only that, but during the process you are also forcing numerous memory leaks upon yourself.

With `student = malloc(...)`, you are allocating a new memory block at each iteration, and then setting this variable to point to that memory block while "forgetting" the previous one (which you will no longer be able to deallocate).

Comment: I made a huge mistake for confusing with array[][].
Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisPark: You're welcome. I haven't referred to the remaining of your code, due to this very basic mistake. I hope that you'll be able to sort out the rest on your own.

Answer (score 1):

This `id[0] = ""` doesn't make any sense. Your compiler should give a compiler error for this or it is misconfigured/broken.

To assign a value to a string, use `strcpy(student[i].id, "")`.

Also, as somebody pointed out, the malloc should not be inside a loop. Just drop the first for loop and use one single malloc call. And don't cast the result from malloc, because doing so is pointless.

```
Student* student = malloc( sizeof(Student[input]) );
```

At the end of the program (when school's out) add `free(student)`.

Comment: That's not the only thing that doesn't make sense in this piece of code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Updated the answer for completeness.

Comment: @RajeevSingh Obviously there needs to be a declared variable called `student`.

Comment: `student = malloc(input * sizeof(Student));` if you recommend dropping the loop.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's equivalent to what I wrote. `sizeof(Student[input])` is clearer, it is self-documenting code telling that an array is allocated.

Comment: Yes it did. I tried to make 100 arrays of student. I tried to make the program that can be changed by user input.

Comment: Jeez, do I have to spell it out to you guys? Updated answer. `input` is indeed the user input. If `Student[input]` doesn't work for you, it is because you are using a 25 year old compiler made by dinosaurs. Please don't write dino C.

Comment: Thanks, I see that `sizeof(Student[input])` (using the type name) is valid syntax on my old compiler, although even my recent one doesn't accept variable length.

Comment: @WeatherVane Visual Studio 2015? Don't use such ancient crap from 1990. GCC is free.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you are asking, but maybe you need this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct student
{
  char id[11];            
} Student;


int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int nbstudents = 0;
  int i;

  printf ("How many students do you want: ");
  scanf("%d",&nbstudents);

  Student *studentarray = malloc(nbstudents * sizeof(Student));

  for(i = 0; i < nbstudents; i++)
  {
    printf ("Enter student id %d: ", i);
    scanf("%s", studentarray[i].id);
  }

  printf ("Students ids entered:\n");

  for(i = 0; i < nbstudents; i++)
  {
    printf ("Student id %d: %s\n", i, studentarray[i].id);
  }

  free(studentarray);

  return 0;
 }
```

Ths `student` structure should probably contain other fields than `id`, for example the name of the student.

Comment: @Lundin corrected thanks, you can delete the comment.

Comment: ah.. Yeah this is what I want. But how can I change data without using scanf function

Comment: @ChrisPark : you can use `strcpy`:  `strcpy(studentarray[i].id, "SOMEID");` . But  `studentarray[i].id =  "SOMEID";` won't work.